# Seaborn style not being applied

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I just updated conda and installed seaborn (v0.9.0). Then started jupyter notebook and tried to plot a seaborn distplot, but strangely it has matplotlib style!
Could someone please help me apply seaborn style with seaborn plots.

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.distplot(tips['total_bill'])
```

[image: Seaborn plot with matplotlib style]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using

```
sns.set()
```

after `%matplotlib inline` as following and see if it works then.

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.set()
sns.distplot(tips['total_bill'])
```